# Quartz.net as service can't configure the quartz_job.xml file to use AdoJobStore

Tags: c#, service, quartz.net

i am using quartz in my project, and i'm storing the jobs in the 
adojobstore, 
i've created a working quartz windows service, but i can't find where 
i can configure the quartz_jobs.xml to use AdoJobstore instead of 
RamJobStore. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quartz_jobs.xml is for describing jobs and triggers. The job store implementation is configured in scheduler factory properties, either by giving them as constructor parameter or by using app.config's quartz section. [See the topic on Quartz.NET tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html) for more information on job store topic.

Comment: well the tutorial need to be updated, because i solved this issue weeks ago, and trust me the configuration lines given in the lessen 9 ain't enough to make it work properly.
all i had to do is to add some configuration lines, i got inspired from the No0peration Project at sourceforge.com
thanks anyway

Comment: @aleo: I've used the documentation and implemented my solution with no problem.